# VirtualBox Error: Failed to open a session for a virtual machine. Module not Found

Tags: virtualbox

I going to run Android Emulator on VirtualBox. All the configuration is right,but when I start virtual machine, the program alerts me:

```
VirtualBox - Error
Failed to open a session for a virtual machine
Android-2.2-Generic
Module not found(VERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND)

Details
Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component:Console
Interface:IConsole{1968b7d3-e3bf-4ceb-99e0-cb7c913317bb}
```

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: Read this article : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1005921

Maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found out that the DNS address in my HOST was pointing to an inexistent machine in the network, in fact it pointed to the GUEST machine (!!!) I was trying to power up.

Once setting the HOST DNS address to 8.8.8.8, the guest powered up.